# Firebase | Problem with collectionGroup query

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use a collectionGroup query to fetch the data from a specified farm, using firebase-functions. Here's my code:

```
app.get('/api/intervals/:farm_id', async (req, res) => {

    const farmId = req.params.farm_id;

    try {

      const querySnapshot = await db
        .collectionGroup('farms')
        .where("id", "==", farmId)
        .get();

      const farmData = [];
    
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

        farmData.push(doc.data());
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());

      });

      return res.status(200).send(farmData);
    
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).send(error);
    }

});
```

There is definitely a farm in the database with the supplied code. For example, if I change the code in `try` to the below, I get the data as expected:

```
    const farmRef = db
      .collection('accounts')
      .doc('lz8V32bjQGa9x1oecUu9')
      .collection('farms')
      .doc(farmId);
    let farm = await farmRef.get();
    let farmData = farm.data();
    return res.status(200).send(farmData);
```

But I want to use a collectionGroup so I don't have to specify the parent account ID also.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your database structure. other than that did you create index for query ?

Comment: @Ashish, structure is quite simple: Parent collection of "Accounts". Each account has a sub-collection of "Farms". Yep, index has been created as per the console link that firebase throws.

Comment: farmid exists in document field ?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding this is related with the fact that in your working code you are assigning directly from `DocumentSnapshot`, while in example in of the issue you are iterating over `QuerySnapshot` returned by `get` from query.

In [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) we can find that documents in `QuerySnapshot` are in array property `docs`.

So I think you should change `forEach` loop accordingly:

```
querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {

        farmData.push(doc.data());
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out that the problem was that my code was looking for a field named `id`. My query works if I manually add a field called ID as highlighted below: [image]